# Jquery: check radio by each table row not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to loop every row of the table and check the radio if not checked by default, we will check the value=Local for it, if already checked by default, just leave it.

my code as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.tableA tr').each(function (index) {
      //processing this row         
      //how to process each cell(table td) where there is checkbox  
      var countChecked = 0;
      console.log("Row: "+index);
        if(!$(this).find('input[type="radio"]').is(":checked")){
          console.log("None Checked");
          countChecked = 1;
        } else {
          var radioValue = $(this).find('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
          console.log("This row has checked: "+radioValue);
        }

        if (countChecked>0){
          $(this).find(':radio[name=radioName][value=Local]').attr('checked', true);        
        }
      });      
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<table class="tableA" border='1'>
<tr>
  <td>
<input type="radio" name="radioName" class="myRadio" value="1" /> 1 <br />
<input type="radio" name="radioName" class="myRadio" value="2" /> 2 <br />
<input type="radio" name="radioName" class="myRadio" value="3" /> 3 <br />
<input type="radio" name="radioName" class="myRadio" value="Local" /> Local <br />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
<input type="radio" name="radioName" class="myRadio" value="1" /> 1 <br />
<input type="radio" name="radioName" class="myRadio" value="2" checked /> 2 <br />
<input type="radio" name="radioName" class="myRadio" value="3" /> 3 <br />
<input type="radio" name="radioName" class="myRadio" value="Local" /> Local <br />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
<input type="radio" name="radioName" class="myRadio" value="1" /> 1 <br />
<input type="radio" name="radioName" class="myRadio" value="2" /> 2 <br />
<input type="radio" name="radioName" class="myRadio" value="3" /> 3 <br />
<input type="radio" name="radioName" class="myRadio" value="Local" /> Local <br />
  </td>
</tr>  
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

[Jsbin Link](http://jsbin.com/rizowimegu/edit?html,console,output)

which is not working, but if i comment out the line:

```
$(this).find(':radio[name=radioName][value=Local]').attr('checked', true);
```

the console will display correctly. Any idea?

Comment: Every `radio` name is `radioName`. Is it correct?

Comment: yes that is correct.

Comment: Young Kyun Jin is correct radio name should be `radioName1`, `radioName2` and `radioName3` for each `tr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real issue is that all the radio items share the same name, so they are actually one big radio group. Which means only one of the 12 can be selected.

Make sure each of the 3 groups has a unique name, and then remove the `name=radioName` from the selector filter.

https://jsfiddle.net/sehmxwwn/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.tableA tr').each(function (index) {
      //processing this row         
      //how to process each cell(table td) where there is checkbox  
      var countChecked = 0;
      console.log("Row: "+index);
        if(!$(this).find('input[type="radio"]').is(":checked")){
          console.log("None Checked");
          countChecked = 1;
        } else {
          var radioValue = $(this).find('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
          console.log("This row has checked: "+radioValue);
        }

        if (countChecked>0){
          $(this).find(':radio[value=Local]').attr('checked', true);        
        }
      });      
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<table class="tableA" border='1'>
<tr>
  <td>
<input type="radio" name="radioName" class="myRadio" value="1" /> 1 <br />
<input type="radio" name="radioName" class="myRadio" value="2" /> 2 <br />
<input type="radio" name="radioName" class="myRadio" value="3" /> 3 <br />
<input type="radio" name="radioName" class="myRadio" value="Local" /> Local <br />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
<input type="radio" name="radioName1" class="myRadio" value="1" /> 1 <br />
<input type="radio" name="radioName1" class="myRadio" value="2" checked /> 2 <br />
<input type="radio" name="radioName1" class="myRadio" value="3" /> 3 <br />
<input type="radio" name="radioName1" class="myRadio" value="Local" /> Local <br />
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
<input type="radio" name="radioName2" class="myRadio" value="1" /> 1 <br />
<input type="radio" name="radioName2" class="myRadio" value="2" /> 2 <br />
<input type="radio" name="radioName2" class="myRadio" value="3" /> 3 <br />
<input type="radio" name="radioName2" class="myRadio" value="Local" /> Local <br />
  </td>
</tr>  
</table>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `prop` instead of `attr` for checked property.

```
$(this).find(':radio[name=radioName][value=Local]').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: not working, try it at jsbin link on the question above

Answer (score 1):

Change the code like this .use `prop` instead of `attr`

```
 $(this).find('input[value=Local]').prop('checked', true);
```

And also do the below things

1. set the `group` of the radio button
2. Don't use the same name for all radio buttons.Because radion buttons are group by name .so use with an individual name for each group

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.tableA tr').each(function(index) {

    var countChecked = 0;
    if (!$(this).find('input[type="radio"]').is(":checked")) {
      countChecked = 1;
    } else {
      var radioValue = $(this).find('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
    }
    if (countChecked > 0) {
      $(this).find('input[value=Local]').prop('checked', true);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tableA" border='1'>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="radioName0" class="myRadio" value="1" /> 1 <br />
        <input type="radio" name="radioName0" class="myRadio" value="2" /> 2 <br />
        <input type="radio" name="radioName0" class="myRadio" value="3" /> 3 <br />
        <input type="radio" name="radioName0" class="myRadio" value="Local" /> Local <br />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>

        <input type="radio" name="radioName1" class="myRadio" value="1" /> 1 <br />
        <input type="radio" name="radioName1" class="myRadio" value="2" checked /> 2 <br />
        <input type="radio" name="radioName1" class="myRadio" value="3" /> 3 <br />
        <input type="radio" name="radioName1" class="myRadio" value="Local" /> Local <br />

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>

        <input type="radio" name="radioName2" class="myRadio" value="1" /> 1 <br />
        <input type="radio" name="radioName2" class="myRadio" value="2" /> 2 <br />
        <input type="radio" name="radioName2" class="myRadio" value="3" /> 3 <br />
        <input type="radio" name="radioName2" class="myRadio" value="Local" /> Local <br />

    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$("input[name=radioName][value='local']").prop("checked",true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Find working/modified [jsBin code](http://jsbin.com/bovawikavo/edit?html,console,output%60)  as per your description.comment if you need any modifications.

Modifications done:

1.used unique name for the radio buttons on each table row(tr).

2.modified below code line

```
if (countChecked>0){
          $(this).find(':radio[value=Local]').prop('checked', 'checked');        
        }
```